# How to customize chart labels for mpandroidchart library

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using the ***mpandroidchart*** library for my chart in which I'm showing day's data for a week, 7 days in total.

For each day, I want the label to be the day's name (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday,...).
However, label are in numbers (0, 1, 2,...).

How do I customize the labels to show strings rather than ints?

Comment: Would you please share a screenshot of output by which we can understand what exactly you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use version greater than or equal to 3.0.1 of library and add below lines to your code:

```
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(getXAxisValues()));
```

Create following method also:

```
private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues()
{
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String> ();

    labels.add( "SUN");
    labels.add( "MON");
    labels.add( "TUE");
    labels.add( "WED");
    labels.add( "THU");
    labels.add( "FRI");
    labels.add( "SAT");
    return labels;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom Formatter for that All you have to do is create one class and set the axis

```
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new DayFormatter());
```

Custom class for Formatter

```
public class DayFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
    return getDay((int) value);
}

String getDay(int day) {
    switch (day) {
        case 1:
            return "Monday";
        default:
            return "";
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
 // creating data values
    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new Entry(30f, 0));
    entries.add(new Entry(12f, 1));
    entries.add(new Entry(12f, 2));

    // creating labels
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
    labels.add("Disability");
    labels.add("Environment");
    labels.add("Food and Farming");
//        Colors
    Integer[] colors = new Integer[]{Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.RED};
    //Set entries in PieDataSet
    PieDataSet pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(entries, "");
    pieDataSet.setDrawValues(false);
    pieDataSet.setColors(Arrays.asList(colors));
//        pieDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS); // set the color
//        Set Data in PieData and PieChart
    PieData data = new PieData(labels, pieDataSet); // initialize PieData
    pieChartSupport.setCenterText(getString(R.string.chart_center_text));
    pieChartSupport.setData(data);
    pieChartSupport.setHoleRadius(80);
    pieChartSupport.setDrawSliceText(false);
    pieChartSupport.setDescription(getString(R.string.supports));
    pieChartSupport.setDrawSliceText(false);
```

This is How you can add days in PieChart provided by MPAndroidChart Library.